# Interleave function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I found this code that builds a list corresponding to the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence):

```
thueMorse :: [Int]
thueMorse = 0 : interleave (map (1-) thueMorse) (tail thueMorse)
    where interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
```

It's perfect and works wonders, but I cannot wrap my head around it. An example:

```
> take 8 thueMorse 
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

If I define the `interleave` function globally and use it I get, and rightly so, an exception:

```
> let interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
> interleave [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[1,4,2,5,3,6*** Exception: <interactive>:29:5-47: Non-exhaustive patterns in function interleave
```

So, how does the above work? Is it because it's an infinite list so it's safe to interleave forever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it works because the input is a pair of infinite lists. That definition of `interleave` only handles the case where its first argument is not empty, ie uses the `:` constructor. But lists have a second constructor (`[]`) which that definition ignores is possible.  A more complete definition would probably look like this, depending on how you want it to handle an empty input:

```
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
interleave [] ys = ys
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception already tells your error: your pattern for `interleave` isn't exhaustive. What happens if you try to use `interleave [] a`? The pattern for the first argument only matches lists with at least one element. That way, [`interleave` is only defined partially](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_functions), that is, not for all possible lists.